# Input and parse JSON with envconfig

Tags: json, go, environment-variables

I'm using Kelsey Hightower's `envconfig` [package](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig) which works like this:

```
set MYAPP_FOO=foo
set MYAPP_BAR={"cat": "dog"}
```

Now I'm trying to build a JSON, the output of which should look like this:

```
{
  "foo": "foo",
  "bar": {"cat": "dog"}
}
```

Instead I get `bar` as a string:

```
{ "foo":"foo",
  "bar": "{\"cat\": \"dog\"}"
}
```

Here's my script:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"
)

type InputOptions struct {
  Foo string
  Bar string
}

type BodyContent struct {
  Foo string `json:"foo"`
  Bar string `json:"bar"`
}

func main() {
  var input_options InputOptions 
  envconfig.Process("myapp", &input_options)
  
  bodyContent := new(BodyContent)
  bodyContent.Foo = input_options.Foo
  bodyContent.Bar = input_options.Bar
    
  jsonOutput,_ := json.Marshal(bodyContent)
  fmt.Println(string(jsonOutput))
}
```

I know it's something to do with the `string` types - no idea what they *should* be though!

Comment: Change the type of `Bar` to `map[string]string`

Comment: try converting bar to struct if cat is fixed or map[string]interface{} in InputOptions and do loop on the bar.

Comment: Marc's suggestion gives me: `{"foo":"foo","bar":{"{\"cat\"":" \"dog\"}"}}` which isn't quite correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a map if you need access to the values:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"
)

type InputOptions struct {
    Foo string
    Bar map[string]string
}

type BodyContent struct {
    Foo string            `json:"foo"`
    Bar map[string]string `json:"bar"`
}

func main() {
    var input_options InputOptions
    envconfig.Process("myapp", &input_options)

    bodyContent := BodyContent(input_options)

    jsonOutput, _ := json.Marshal(bodyContent)
    fmt.Println(string(jsonOutput)) // {"foo":"foo","bar":{"cat":"dog"}}
}
```

Use [json.RawMessage](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) if you don't care about the values:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"
)

type InputOptions struct {
    Foo string
    Bar json.RawMessage
}

type BodyContent struct {
    Foo string          `json:"foo"`
    Bar json.RawMessage `json:"bar"`
}

func main() {
    var input_options InputOptions
    envconfig.Process("myapp", &input_options)

    bodyContent := BodyContent(input_options)

    jsonOutput, _ := json.Marshal(bodyContent)
    fmt.Println(string(jsonOutput)) // {"foo":"foo","bar":{"cat":"dog"}}
}
```

Comment: Thanks peter but your top example gives: `{"foo":"foo","bar":{"{\"cat\"":" \"dog\"}"}}` not the `{"foo":"foo", "bar":{"cat": "dog"}}` that I need.

Comment: json.RawMessage version was what I needed. Thanks.